# Recall Jquery in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to click on a canvas, move it to the map, drop it on the map. After dropping it on the map, they can select the canvas on the map and move it again. The process is repeated. I have trouble with the ignoreMouseMove variable, it does not reset to false and is always true

Here is link to the demo: https://pokemon-map-electro2k.c9users.io/index.html

```
var moveCanvas = function ($canvas, e) {
    $(".map ul li." + $canvas).offset({
        left: e.pageX - 30,
        top: e.pageY - 30
    });
};

// When user first click on canvas
var onmousemove = function ($canvas) {

    var ignoreMouseMove = false;

    // Make canvas follow cursor in the map area
    $(".map").mousemove(function (e) {
        if (ignoreMouseMove) return;    // event handling mousemove is "disabled"
        moveCanvas($canvas, e);
    }).click(function () {
        // "re-enable" mousemove
        ignoreMouseMove = true;

        // When canvas is click on again within the map area, make canvas follow cursor
        $(".map ul li").click(function () {
            $(".map").mousemove(function (e) {
                if (!ignoreMouseMove) return;
                moveCanvas($canvas, e);
            }).click(function () {
                // Click function does not work anymore. ignoreMouseMove can't be reset. It is always true
                ignoreMouseMove = false; 
            })
        });

    });

};
```

Comment: behavior wanted is not very clear ... what do you mean by *"recall"*? Suggest you use a drag/drop library instead of re-inventing the wheel

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `.off()`, use a boolean variable which indicates whether you want to ignore the `mousemove` event or not, but keeping the `mousemove` event handler in place:

```
var onmousemove = function ($canvas) {
    var ignoreMouseMove = false;
    // Make canvas follow cursor in the map area
    $(".map").mousemove(function (e) {
        if (ignoreMouseMove) return; // event handling is "disabled"
        $(".map ul li." + $canvas).offset({
            left: e.pageX,
            top: e.pageY
        });
    }).click(function () {
        ignoreMouseMove = true;
        $(".map ul li").click(function () {
            // "re-enable" mousemove
            ignoreMouseMove = false;
       });
    });
};
```

Comment: the ignoreMouseMove can't be reset to false?

Comment: There was a mistake in the script; the last assignment statement should be `= false`. Updated.